# Get Facebook page's stream from a Global Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I have a little problem with the Facebook api.

I am doing a very simple FQL request to get a Page's stream like this one :

```
SELECT post_id, type, likes, comments FROM stream WHERE source_id = X
```

It works just well. But, when I do the same request on "huge pages" like Coca Cola or Starbucks, all stream posts have an empty "type", "likes count" and "comments count".

I don't really understand why. I am thinking about a "Global Page" with country code error, but I just can't find information on this.

Any idea ?

**Edit**: just try another request to get the page global child IDs, but looks like Coca Cola and Starbucks doesn't use the Global Page system.

```
starbucks?fields=global_brand_children.username,global_brand_parent_page
```

So, any idea why my first request return empty infos when getting stream content ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with "huge pages". It's only that "huge pages" have a lot of posts and shares from fans. Indeed, the `stream` table provides ALL the activities of the page.

The `type` of a stream activity will be `null` when the content comes from a user. When it comes from the page owner, it will be an int. See the description of the `type` field on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/.

The reason why you might get a `null` as a `like count` is that you came across a post which has the `can_like` or `can_comment` fields set to `false`. These posts cannot be liked or commented because they are present **outside** of the page (i.e. on a user timeline or on particular website) and their owner didn't allow public likes or comments (even if publicly visible). If you are going to find such activities in the stream of the page is because they **tagged the page** in their message or photo.

---

**Edit** in answer to your first comment.

**Question: why doesn't the following query give back the posts from the owner of the page:**

```
SELECT actor_id, message 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id = 40796308305 
      AND actor_id = 40796308305
```

Let's see how many results this query CAN give back:

```
SELECT actor_id, message 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id = 40796308305
```

Okay, [we get 17 results](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20actor_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20=%2040796308305). Why 17? I don't know.

When you add `AND actor_id = 40796308305` to your request, it will checks among these 17 results which ones have `40796308305` as an `actor_id`.

Answer? [None](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20actor_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20=%2040796308305%20AND%20actor_id%20=%2040796308305)!

Because it only checks the 17 first results, you'll have to indicate a `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT actor_id, message 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id = 40796308305 
      AND actor_id = 40796308305 
 LIMIT 100
```

And there you get [what you want](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20actor_id,%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20=%2040796308305%20AND%20actor_id%20=%2040796308305%20LIMIT%20100).

This is one of the Facebook API's subtlety. Documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: Thxs a lot Stephane, but I still don't get it.

Let's try this request (coca cola ID): SELECT post_id, type, likes, comments, source_id, actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = 40796308305 AND actor_id = 40796308305 give me a data = [] result. But when I look at the coca cola Page, there is posts with likes and comments. (french content)